# Transformed my model now my residual standard error is too high?

Tags: r, multiple-regression, data-transformation, residuals

Here's my original Residual vs Fitted plot. The RSE is 4.974
[image]

Because it's not linear, I tried transforming it by setting the response to the power of 4. Now my model looks like this. [image]

My RSE now is 5175000. Is that normal? Did I do something wrong? Should I have done a different transformation on my model? If so, what kind?

Answer (score 2):

Without understanding the underlying data it is difficult to judge.  Randomly transforming your dependent variable to a power of whatever will not help.  Maybe your original model is not that bad.  Actually, it seems pretty good.

A simple way to check if your model adds value is to compare the Standard Error or Root Mean Squared Error (RMSE) of your model with the standard deviation of Y.  I presume the RMSE of your model is 4.974.  Let's say the standard deviation of Y is close to 10.  In this case, you could say that your model reduces the estimated error of Y by close to 50%.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I'm using countries data with various independent variables predicting Life Expectancy. The model looked off to me because although it looks like it's near 0, the red line is not that horizontal and I'm not sure if the linearity assumption holds. So I didn't know what transformation I needed to do, or if I even needed one.

Comment: No model is perfect.  This begs some lenience regarding strict visual interpretation of linearity.  Check my modified answer.

Comment: I had modified my answer substantially.  Somehow, a full two days later, it is still not updated.